Standardized regression coefficient
I was wondering the following: Does the standardized coefficient on X1 in a regression of Y on X1, X2, ...,XN go to one, as the bivariate correlation of Y and X1 goes to one. If so, why?
Or is it possible that some of the variation in Y is still explained by the other X2,X3...

The standardized coefficient can be higher than 1, or lower than -1.
It's nothing to do with whether some of the variance in Y is still explained by the other predictors. It typically happens in the presence of very high collinearity - and (in my experience) this is most common in non-linear regression.
Example (using R):
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)

set.seed(420)

S <- c(1.00, 0.90, -0.10,
       0.90, 1.00, 0.10,
       -0.10, 0.10, 1.00)  %>%
  matrix(nrow = 3)

d <- MASS::mvrnorm(m = c(0, 0, 0), Sigma = S, n = 1000) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
   x1 = scale(V1),
   x2 = scale(V2),
   y  = scale(V3)
  )

lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = d) %>% summary()

Which gives:
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.513e-17  2.773e-02    0.00        1    
x1          -1.018e+00  6.103e-02  -16.68   <2e-16 ***
x2           1.043e+00  6.103e-02   17.09   <2e-16 ***

